# Redirect users to a page only when they are signing in for the first time

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm trying to find a way to identify if a user is doing a first time sign in (can't rely solely on registration to determine this) through firebase. Basically, on any type of sign in (Email, phone, facebook, google, etc), I want to check if this is the first time we are adding this user to firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of Michele's answer...

I'd probably throw in there you can use the Firebase Functions to create a document and add it to a collection of `profiles` (using Firestore or the RTDB) on account creation.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

export const userOnCreate: functions.CloudFunction<admin.auth.UserInfo> = functions.auth.user()
  .onCreate((event: functions.Event<admin.auth.UserRecord>) => {
    const user: admin.auth.UserRecord = event.data;

    return admin.firestore().collection('profiles').doc(user.uid).set({
      email: user.email, // or username
      firstTimeSignedIn: false
    });
  });
```

Add the boolean value for `firstTimeSignedIn` and on sign in query the doc. If it doesn't exist (because the function didn't trigger quick enough), you know that this is there first time. And if the value is false you know it's their first time. After the redirect though, you can `set` the value with a merge...

```
firestore.collection('profiles').doc(uid).set({firstTimeSignedIn: true}, { merge: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a simple boolean in the User Object:

```
class/interface User {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    // other properties...
    firstTimeSignedIn: boolean;
}
```

if the firstTimeSignedIn is `true` you can redirect and set it to `false`.

Comment: Firebase doesn't allow direct addition of new fields to the defined objects (User). But I might end up doing something similar to your answer in terms of adding it as metadata when I store the user's info to the backend (not the firebase user storage).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine whether a user is new or existing on sign in/up, you should just check the [`userCredential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#.AdditionalUserInfo) in `userCredential` returned in all sign in methods.